# why am i not able to install any package?

Tags: r, install.packages

since 2 days ago Whenever i try to insrall a package R gives me this error:

package installation in ‘C:/Users/Win10/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(because ‘lib’ is not specified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/dplyr_1.0.10.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1306071 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

package ‘dplyr’ opened with success with sum cntrol MD5
Error in install.packages : ERROR:  faild change lock for the directory ‘C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2’
Removal ‘C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2/00LOCK’

i try to reinstall R and to remove "00LOCK"

Comment: Try closing down R, navigating to the directory, deleting it, then restarting R again.

Comment: So if you go to that path, is the `00LOCK` file actually there? Can you you verify that's it's deleted before you run `install.packages`? Do you only have one R session open and running? Is this your own computer or a shared computer with multiple users?

Comment: thank you @AllanCameron! your suggestion works